# Retrieving specific documents for cts:search (MarkLogic)

Tags: marklogic

I am currently trying to see if I can do cts:searches based on a certain path rather then using uri matches such as [uri-match](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uri-match) and [directory-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:directory-query). The issue is I have uri data such as

`/car/ferrari/01
/car/ferrari/01/belongs/to/person/mary/01`

I also know that we can do path filter by running a query such as

`cts:search(fn:doc()/car_data, .....)`

But the issue with this is that I believe Xpath does not work with SPARQL queries.

Due to this I am unable to directory search for all cars or use uri-match to retrieve all car documents. Of course I am able to somewhat work around this with

`cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("car_part"), "PRC*", "wildcarded")`

Any other form of work around or recommendation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question boils down to wanting to have directory query functionality without doing a directory query. So I’m gonna need to understand the requirements there a bit more.

Comment: @hunterhacker what sort of requirements do you need? In general I believe your summarization is correct and I understand that there is work arounds such as creating a collection to do collections query on them. However, I am mainly curious if I can actually do something like a `cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:path-word-query("/car_data/car_parts","PRC"))`

Comment: I think you might be looking for `cts:field-word-query` on a field index that is configured for specific paths.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding the question though. XPath is unrelated to directories and uris, and even less sure where SPARQL would or should play a role in this.

Comment: I think cts:field-word-query might be what I need. As for the reason I related the query to sparql is to show that I am unable to use the same path filtering approach for SPARQL so I wanted to know if is it possible or not to do something similar in SPARQL. @grtjn

Comment: Hard to judge without seeing the actual SPARQL code, and relevant code to invoke it..